# Resource file is undefined on scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a resource file that sometimes is read, and sometimes is undefined and crashes all the application. I do not know why it only works sometimes and it is causing me trouble to figure a solution out. On my controllers I am passing the service that I created to read the file which is `appResourcesService`:

```
app.controller('CommonController', ['$scope', '$location', 'appResourcesService',
    function ($scope,  $location, appResourcesService)
```

And the service to read resoruces is the following:

```
'use strict';
app.factory('appResourcesService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var appResourcesServiceFactory = {};

    appResourcesServiceFactory.getResources = function ($scope, language, locale) {

        var languageFilePath = 'resources/AppResources.json';

        $resource(languageFilePath).get().$promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.appResources = data;
        }, function (reason) {
            var defaultLanguageFilePath = 'resources/AppResources.json';
            $resource(defaultLanguageFilePath).get(function (data) {
                $scope.appResources = data;
            });
        });
    };
    return appResourcesServiceFactory;
}]);
```

Like I said, sometimes it works without any kind of problem, but sometimes when in the controller I reach the piec eof code `$scope.appResources`, appResources is undefined. I think it is maybe because it reaches there before the file is read, but I am not being able to find a solution to avoid it.

Comment: Without answer to you question, I see a serious problem of design in your application. The service should not know your scope. It's not his responsibility to manage the scope. The scope is know by the controller and the view. The service should be invoke by the controller and return data or, if it's asynchronous, a promise. This is the controller that get the data from the service, process it and inject it in scope.

Comment: Your problem is certainly related to this bad design. Because your service not returning promise I suppose you probably try to access `$scope.appResources` before `$resource(languageFilePath).get()` was resolved.

Comment: @Techniv I agree, it has clearly a bad design and that is exacly the problem. So you say my service should return a promise and I should call a function inside my controller that has that function as return?

Comment: Yes. I upvoted for the answer of @gyc. It's a good exemple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory should return a promise.
It's the job of your controller to handle data. (I use $http as it's cleaner)

```
app.factory('appResourcesService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var appResourcesServiceFactory = {};

    appResourcesServiceFactory.getResources = function () {
      var languageFilePath = 'resources/AppResources.json';
      return $http.get(languageFilePath).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
    )};

    return appResourcesServiceFactory;
}]);
```

You resolve the promise inside the controller with .then to get the data and set your scope.

```
appResourcesServiceFactory.getResources().then(function(data) {
   $scope.appResources = data;
})
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Provider 'appResourcesService' must return a value from $get factory method.

Comment: sorry dumb me, I removed   return appResourcesServiceFactory; it is ok now. Add it to your answer please :)